# Batch Conditional INSERT INTO statement in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to `UPSERT` in Postgres, but my version is below 9.5 so I cannot use `ON CONFILICT`. I found something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET field='C', field2='Z' WHERE id=3;
INSERT INTO table (id, field, field2)
       SELECT 3, 'C', 'Z'
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id=3);
```

But how can I do this with **batch** values?
This statement might can express what I want to do (It cannot work):

```
INSERT INTO result_data (HOST_ID, RESOURCE_TYPE, TIMESTAMP, UPPER, LOWER, AVG) 
    (values ("xxxxx", "cpu", 1544313900, 80, 70, 75), ("aaaaaa", "cpu", 1544314000, 80, 70, 75))
    AS result2(HOST_ID, RESOURCE_TYPE, TIMESTAMP, UPPER, LOWER, AVG) 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM result_data WHERE result2.HOST_ID = result_data.HOST_ID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple `VALUES` in a `WITH` clause ( CTE ) and refer to it in the `SELECT` part of  a `INSERT INTO.. SELECT`

```
with result2(HOST_ID, RESOURCE_TYPE, TIMESTAMP, UPPER, LOWER, AVG)  AS
(
 VALUES  ('xxxxx', 'cpu', 1544313900,  80, 70, 75 ), 
         ('aaaaaa', 'cpu', 1544314000, 80, 70, 75 ) 
)
 SELECT * FROM   result2 r2 
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
           ( 
             SELECT 1 
               FROM   result_data r 
              WHERE   r.host_id = r2.host_id )
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=a0b6e4792d0651c590610cb86db48460)

Comment: It works! Thx a lot!   One more question, is there any better solution on `UPSERT` with the version below 9.5 than using `UPDATE` and `INSERT` these two statements?

Comment: @Jack : There could be, better option is to upgrade Postgres version

Comment: Huh! But I do not have the right to upgrade the environment.. Thx again!